# RoR Tutorial Michael Hartl Deleting Microposts also Deletes Users

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am experiencing a strange problem while trying to implement the sample app in Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial.

When I delete a micropost, the following happens:

1. The micropost gets deleted.
2. The user Also gets deleted.
3. Get directed to the Sign Up page.

Only the first step is supposed to happen. The user is not supposed to get deleted. The console trace shows the following when I delete a micropost:

```
Started DELETE "/microposts/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-23 11:35:31 -0400
Processing by MicropostsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"clfdQ1F/1ewiDnuae9OpVXSZ3S/wtieCrVYNM+Y1838=", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'cUs3NX6FrzU-XnkCbGE4wg' LIMIT 1
  Micropost Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = 1 AND "microposts"."id" = 1 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  DELETE FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
   (12.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 16.0ms)
```

I am not sure why the DELETE FROM "users" is being sent.

My application.js file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions,    only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts,  only: [:create, :destroy]

  root :to => 'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

And the microposts_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end

  private

   def correct_user
     @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
     redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
   end
end
```

You can see above how the destroy action is being implemented (as specified in the tutorial). So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is the app/models/micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  # here we removed :user_id from attr_accessable for security reasons
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 } 
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'
end
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What does your `app/models/micropost.rb` look like?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Marek. I added the code for micropost.rb above. The dependent: :destroy was explained in the tutorial to serve the purpose of deleting all the microposts belonging to the user if the user gets deleted.

Comment: @AbeChallah, if you want to delete all microposts belonging to the user then you should add `dependent: :destroy` in `User.rb` like `has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Thanks a lot Vinod. I understand how it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `Micropost` model.  The following line is deleting the `user` associated with the `Micropost`:

```
belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
```

Replace that line with:

```
belongs_to :user
```

and you won't see user associated getting deleted.

Please read through the documentation on "Dependent associations" here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

**Update:**

If you want to delete all microposts belonging to a user then you should add `dependent: :destroy` in `User.rb` like the following:

```
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: @AbeChallah, have a look at my comment in your question.

Comment: I did Vinod. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Micropost` class is saying that the user should be destroyed when a micropost is destroyed with the `dependent: :destroy` option on the `belongs_to :user`.

From the [documentation for belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) for `:dependent` **If set to :destroy, the associated object is destroyed when this object is.**

So, if you remove the `dependent: :destroy` you won't get the problem.